# Hide helper methods in Ruby mixin

Tags: ruby, private, mixins

A Ruby module used for logging is being used almost in every class as a mixin. Therefore it must contain as low public methods as possible to avoid name collisions.

The problem is that each public method uses the same helper methods and they become class members after mixing in. These helper methods are candidates for name collisions.

How to keep helper methods in module but hide them from mixin target class?

Converting them to private makes them completely unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're ignoring the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Consider refactoring to use dependency injection for this kind of stuff.

Basically something along the lines of:

```
module LoggerModule
  def notice(m)
    @logger.notice(m)
  end
end

class Logger
  def notice(m)
    ...
  end

  def internal(arg)
    ...
  end
end

class Foo
  include LoggerModule

  def initialize(logger)
    @logger = logger
  end
end

Foo.new(Logger.new)
```

Tip: look into delegation, and possibly Module#prepend, for cleaner ways to write the above. (My Ruby is a bit rusty.)

Comment: Thank you for terminology. My aim was to minimize impact on source code down to just using the `include` directive and several `log` method calls.